# Download blocked by chrome version 76.* and above with vaadin 8

Tags: google-chrome, download, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using vaadin version 8.8.6 and chrome version 76.0.3809.132 while downloading a file i am getting below error : "[Intervention] Download in ad frame without user activation is not allowed. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6311883621531648 for more details." On degrading chrome version to 71.xxx It works fine. Can i bypass this ad frame? or is there any other way to solve this issue.